# Access client device details Apache redirect using mod_ *

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working on Apache redirects.

I would like to do redirect web request based on the client device name/model/Os/browser.

Can we access it using mod_rewrite or any other mod methods.

I knew that this info will be present in user Agent header.

Can some one help how to access client device information while doing apache redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` variable in mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipad [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ipad_users/ [L,R]
```

Replace `ipad` with a regular expression to capture what user-agents you want to redirect. [This site](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) has a pretty comprehensive list of user-agents.